# how can i take real time photo without going to gallery on xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

now , i'm trying to take a photo with a button and i'll send it to database without saving it to gallery ,My constraint is that user can't take a photo from gallery it should be a real time , so how can i do this ?

Comment: Have a look at these thread for the exception: [mediaplugin-argument-exception](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119942/mediaplugin-argument-exception-unable-to-get-file-location) and [android-file-provider-setup](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/README.md#android-file-provider-setup)

Answer (score 0):

use the [Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#usage) plugin

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    }); 
};
```

Comment: i used "using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;usingPlugin.Media; " and put this code in try {} , the application goes to catch ().

Comment: yup , i did it and trying to use the DefaultCamera but no thing

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: unable to get file location , this most likely means that the file  provider info. is not set on the android mainfest